# Find elements that commonly appear next to each other in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to find values that commonly appear next to each other in an array.

E.G. given the array:

```
["dog","cat","goat","dog","cat","elephant","dog","cat","pig","seal","dog","cat","pig","monkey"]
```

it should return something similar to:

```
[[["dog","cat"],4],[["cat","pig"],2],[["dog","cat","pig"],2]]
```

Here is some better data: https://pastebin.com/UG4iswrZ

Help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my current failed attempt at doing something similar:

```
function findAssociations(words){
  var temp = [],tempStore = [],store = [],found = false;
  //loop through the words counting occurrances of words together with a window of 5
  for(var i = 0;i<words.length-1;i++){
    if(i % 5 == 0){
      //on every fith element, loop through store attempting to add combinations of words stored in tempStore
      for(var j = 0;j<5;j++){
        temp = []
        //create the current combination
        for(var k = 0;k<j;k++){
          temp.push(tempStore[k]);
        }
        //find if element is already stored, if it is, increment the occurrence counter
        for(var k = 0;k<store.length;k++){
          if(store[k][0]===temp){
            found = true;
            store[k][1] = store[k][1]+1;
          }
        }
        //if it isn't add it
        if(found == false){
          store.push([temp,1]);
        }
        found == false;
      }
      tempStore = [];
    } else {
      //add word to tempStore if it i isnt a multiple of 5
      tempStore.push(words[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

This script is doesn't remove combinations that appear once,it doesn't sort the output by occurrences, nor does it work. It is just an outline of how a possible solution might work (as suggested by benvc).

Comment: Why don't you have a `["cat", "pig"], 2` here ?

Comment: Define "commonly appear". What appearance frequency is your lower bound? Is there a size limit on sub-sequences?

Comment: Shouldn't `["dog","cat"],4] be ["dog","cat"],5]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a generic solution working with multiple group sizes.**

You specify a range of group sizes, for example `[2,4]` for groups of 2 to 4 elements and a minimum number of occurrences.

The function then generates all groups of neighbours of the given sizes, sorts each group and counts the duplicates. The sorting step can be removed is the order in the groups matters.

The duplicates are counted by creating a dictionary whose keys are the group elements sorted and jointed with a special marker. The values in the dictionary are the counts.

It then returns the groups sorted by occurences and then by group size.

```js
const data = ["dog","cat","goat","dog","cat","elephant","dog","cat","pig","seal","dog","cat","pig","monkey"];

function findSimilarNeighbors(groupSizeRange, minOccurences, data) {
  const getNeighbors = (size, arr) => arr.reduce((acc, x) => {
    acc.push([]);
    for (let i = 0; i < size; ++ i) {
      const idx = acc.length - i - 1;
      (acc[idx] || []).push(x);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []).filter(x => x.length === size);

  const groups = [];
  for (let groupSize = groupSizeRange[0]; groupSize <= groupSizeRange[1]; ++groupSize) {
    groups.push(...getNeighbors(groupSize, data));
  }
  const groupName = group => group.sort().join('@#@'); // use a separator that won't occur in the strings

  const groupsInfo = groups.reduce((acc, group) => {
    const name = groupName(group);
    acc[name] = acc[name] || {};
    acc[name] = { group, count: (acc[name].count || 0) + 1 };
    return acc;
  }, {});
  
  return Object.values(groupsInfo)
    .filter(group => group.count >= minOccurences)
    .sort((a, b) => {
      const countDiff = b.count - a.count;
      return countDiff ? countDiff : b.group.length - a.group.length;
    })
    .map(({ group, count }) => [group, count]);
};

console.log(findSimilarNeighbors([2, 4], 2, data));
console.log(findSimilarNeighbors([4, 4], 2, data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. It only finds pairs, but you could modify it to find sets of 3, 4, etc, based on what you `%` by

```
const animals = ['dog','cat','goat','dog','cat','elephant','dog','cat','pig','seal','dog','cat','pig','monkey'];

let pairs = ',';
animals.forEach((animal, i) => {
  let separator = ',';
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    separator = ';'
  }
  pairs += animal + separator;
});

const evenPairs = pairs.split(',');
const oddPairs = pairs.split(';');
const allPairs = evenPairs.concat(oddPairs).map(pair => pair.replace(/[;,]/, ' '));

let result = {}

allPairs.forEach(pair => {
  if (pair.length) {
    if (result[pair] === undefined) {
      result[pair] = 1;
    } else {
      result[pair]++;
    }
  }
});
```

results in:

```
dog: 1
cat elephant: 1
cat goat: 1
cat pig: 2
dog cat: 4
elephant dog: 1
goat dog: 1
monkey : 1
pig monkey: 1
pig seal: 1
seal dog: 1
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wvuvnr

Answer (score 0):

You need to be clear what you mean by close and how close. Just looking at first neighbours you could try:

```js
const findAssociations = words => {
    const associations = {}

    for (let i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
        const word = words[i]
        const wordRight = words[i+1]

        const wordOne = word < wordRight ? word : wordRight;
        const wordTwo = word < wordRight ? wordRight : word;

        const keys = Object.keys(associations)
        const key = `${wordOne}:${wordTwo}`
        if (keys.indexOf(key) >= 0) {
            associations[key]++
        } else {
            associations[key] = 1
        }
    }

    const keys = Object.keys(associations)
    const values = Object.values(associations)

    const zipped = keys.map((key, index) => [key, values[index]])
    zipped.sort((a, b) => a[1] < b[1] ? 1 : -1);

    return zipped;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-3ppdit

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function inside another function and add every time an element to `["dog", "cat"]`

```js
const arr = ["dog", "cat", "goat", "dog", "cat", "dog", "cat", "elephant", "dog", "cat", "pig", "seal", "dog", "cat", "pig", "monkey"]


const findArrayInArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
  let count = 0,
    arrString1 = arr1.join(""),
    arrString2 = arr2.join("");
  while (arrString2.indexOf(arrString1) > -1) {
    count += 1;
    arrString2 = arrString2.replace(arrString1, '');
  }
  return count;
}

console.log(`["dog", "cat"] exist ${findArrayInArray(["dog", "cat"], arr)} times`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each item in the list is a delimiter of a set, and each set counts once for each item (i.e. `["dog", "cat", "goat"]` counts as `["dog", "cat"]` and `["dog", "cat", "goat"]`, and assuming you don't want any single occurrences, then here's one way:

```
const full_list = ["dog","cat","goat","dog","cat","dog","cat","elephant","dog","cat","pig","seal","dog","cat","pig","monkey"];

// create list of unique items
const distinct = (value, index, self) => {
    return self.indexOf(value) ===index;
}
const unique_items = full_list.filter(distinct);

// get all patterns
var pre_report = {};
for (var i in unique_items) {
    item = unique_items[i];
    var pattern = [item];

    var appending = false;
    for (var j = full_list.indexOf(item) + 1; j < full_list.length; ++j) {
         const related_item = full_list[j];
         if (item == related_item) {
             pattern = [item]
             continue;
         }

         pattern.push(related_item);
         if (pattern in pre_report) {
             ++pre_report[pattern];
         } else {
             pre_report[pattern] = 1;
         }  
    }
}

// filter out only single occurring patterns
var report = {};
for (key in pre_report) {
    if (pre_report[key] > 1) {
        report[key] = pre_report[key];
    }
}

console.log(report);
```

produces:

```
{ 'dog,cat': 5, 'dog,cat,pig': 2, 'cat,pig': 2 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do but I get "Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" when I run this. Is this an error with the code or is it just because I'm working with large files?

Comment: @Eidolon: Yes, I tried your pastebin data and got the same result.  Probably a funciton of the size of the data, and the distance between the delimiters.  Perhaps putting a "distance limit" - or more likely better use of memory.  I don't have a lot of time at the moment, but I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: That would be very helpful. I'm trying to crunch quite a lot of data, the paste bin is only a quarter of one query...

Comment: When I come back to this, the first thing I'll try is replacing part that populates pre_report with a dump to file.  Then process the file (simple count at that point).  Maybe while waiting for me you can play with that.  Additionally: does it have to be javascript against an array in memory?  Have you tried putting the data in a database and run analytics/queries?  Also: given this answers your question as asked, would you consider marking it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Okay Ill give it a shot. No it doesn't need to be, but just because I am already working with lots of complex queries, keeping extra ones down to a minimal would be useful.