# How do I check for word pairs in a string?

Tags: javascript, count, cpu-word

I have the code below which works perfectly in creating a CSV list of word occurences in  a string (massive .txt file), that looks like this:

```
Name;Total
THE;23562
OF;15954
AND;15318
IN;12159
TO;11879
A;11145
I;6135
WAS;6045
etc...
```

What I want now is word pairs of two, and maybe even three if it proves easy enough. So something like

```
Name;Total
OF THE;25
FROM THE;20
BY WHICH;13
OF WHICH;5
etc...
```

How can I modify my existing code to check for pairs instead of single words?

```
//chrisjopa.com/2016/04/21/counting-word-frequencies-with-javascript/

var fs = require('fs');
var file = 'INPUT.txt';

//Create Headers for the CSV File
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;  
const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({  

//Define Pathname to your choice
  path: 'Data1.csv',
  header: [
    {id: 'name', title: 'Name'},
    {id: 'total', title: 'Total'},
  ]
});

// read file from current directory
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {

  if (err) throw err;

  var wordsArray = splitByWords(data);
  var wordsMap = createWordMap(wordsArray);
  var finalWordsArray = sortByCount(wordsMap);

//Write CSV Output File
  csvWriter  
  .writeRecords(finalWordsArray)
  .then(()=> console.log('DONE'));

});


function splitByWords (text) {

  // Removes all special characters, then white spaces, 
  //then converts to all capital letters, then splits the words
  var noPunctuation = text.replace(/[\.,-\/#!$%\^&\*;:{}�=\-_'`’~"()@\+\?><\[\]\+]/g, '');
  var noExtraSpaces = noPunctuation.replace(/\s{2,}/g," ");
  var allUpperCase  = noExtraSpaces.toUpperCase();
  var wordsArray    = allUpperCase.split(/\s+/);
  return wordsArray;
}

//This is the part in the code that I feel is the place to check for word 
//pairs, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to write it.
function createWordMap (wordsArray, ) {

  // create map for word counts
  var wordsMap = {};

  wordsArray.forEach(function (key) {
    if (wordsMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      wordsMap[key]++;
    } else {
      wordsMap[key] = 1;
    }
  });

  return wordsMap;

}


function sortByCount (wordsMap) {

  // sort by count in descending order
  var finalWordsArray = [];
  finalWordsArray = Object.keys(wordsMap).map(function(key) {
    return {

      name: key,
      total: wordsMap[key]

    };
  });

  finalWordsArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.total - a.total;
  });

  return finalWordsArray;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to add that the code should check every single word pair occuring in the string. For instance the text I just written: (sorry I, I need, need to, to add, add that, etc...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find elements that commonly appear next to each other in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55067241/find-elements-that-commonly-appear-next-to-each-other-in-an-array)

Comment: Don't see it as a pair of words `([a-zA-Z]+?){2}` -- treat it as one string with a space between `([a-zA-Z]+?\s[a-zA-Z]+?)`

Comment: @Seabottom, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55069158/9325419), it might be helpful, as it seems to be answering the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `wordsArray`, create another array that puts together every pair of words. For example, from a `wordsArray` of

```
['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Buzz']
```

create:

```
['Foo Bar', 'Bar Baz', 'Baz Buzz']
```

Then, you can use the *exact same function* you already have to count up the number of occurrences of each pair - just call `createWordMap` with it (and then `sortByCount`). For example:

```js
const wordsArray = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Buzz', 'Foo', 'Bar'];
const wordPairsArray = [];
for (let i = 1; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {
  wordPairsArray.push(wordsArray[i - 1] + ' ' + wordsArray[i]);
}
const wordPairMap = createWordMap(wordPairsArray);
const wordPairCount = sortByCount(wordPairMap);
console.log(wordPairCount);


// the following is your original code:
function createWordMap(wordsArray, ) {
  // create map for word counts
  var wordsMap = {};
  wordsArray.forEach(function(key) {
    if (wordsMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      wordsMap[key]++;
    } else {
      wordsMap[key] = 1;
    }
  });
  return wordsMap;
}
function sortByCount(wordsMap) {
  // sort by count in descending order
  var finalWordsArray = [];
  finalWordsArray = Object.keys(wordsMap).map(function(key) {
    return {
      name: key,
      total: wordsMap[key]

    };
  });
  finalWordsArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.total - a.total;
  });
  return finalWordsArray;
}
```

To extend this to more than just pairs, just change the loop to join together a dynamic number of elements:

```js
function combineWords(words, wordsInItem) {
  const items = [];
  for (let i = wordsInItem - 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    const start = i - (wordsInItem - 1);
    const end = i + 1;
    items.push(words.slice(start, end).join(' '));
  }
  return items;
}
function getCount(words, wordsInItem) {
  const combinedWords = combineWords(words, wordsInItem);
  const map = createWordMap(combinedWords);
  const count = sortByCount(map);
  console.log(count);
}

getCount(['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Buzz', 'Foo', 'Bar'], 2);
getCount(['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz', 'Buzz', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'], 3);





// the following is your original code:
function createWordMap(wordsArray, ) {
  // create map for word counts
  var wordsMap = {};
  wordsArray.forEach(function(key) {
    if (wordsMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      wordsMap[key]++;
    } else {
      wordsMap[key] = 1;
    }
  });
  return wordsMap;
}
function sortByCount(wordsMap) {
  // sort by count in descending order
  var finalWordsArray = [];
  finalWordsArray = Object.keys(wordsMap).map(function(key) {
    return {
      name: key,
      total: wordsMap[key]

    };
  });
  finalWordsArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.total - a.total;
  });
  return finalWordsArray;
}
```

Comment: Why isn't it possible? By constructing a new array from the `wordsArray`, you *will* have an array that contains all word pairs in the string. No extra information is needed that you don't already have in your original implementation, you just need to manipulate it a bit.

Comment: Yes, sorry I realised that as soon as posted it, which is why I deleted my comment. This is just the solution I was looking for, thank you very much. :)